Google AdSense ads are not showing after page refresh
first of all, this is not our site and I recently started working as a IT support, that's why I'm still figuring out a lot of things. So, sorry if I can't provide all the needed information.
A client of our firm has reached out to us to help with Google AdSense ads not showing up on his page. What we've noticed is that they do show up the first time you visit the site and consent to cookies. First refresh of the page and they disappear until you don't clear the browser's cache. I definitely know it's not an issue on my side, my colleagues have looked into it and they have the same issue.
Ads code are inserted into a module. Browser console, Joomla debug doesn't show any errors at all. So I'm at a loss here why it happens.
We don't have access to client's AdSense account, but if really needed, we might ask for it or at least look into it with him remotely.
Joomla version is 2.5.28
Site in question: de2.lt
Thank you in advance!

The problem occurs with the string.
I have fixed more than a dozen AdSense publisher accounts.
The problem is not on your side. It is an internal error.
I can help you. But it requires access to AdSense (user permissions).

Could you elaborate what do we need to do to fix this? Because we definitely can't give out our clients login access and we're not even sure if the client will be willing to provide access to his AdSense account. So most likely we'll have to tell him how to solve it himself or do it remotely when connected to his PC.

I can. You may not transfer login access (username and password). Access is set by adding an email to the AdSense panel.
Without access to AdSense, it is impossible to fix.

Well, the client refused any further help. So we don't have access ourselves anyways. If it's not hard, could you explain on what needs to be done to solve this issue? So we could know what we can try to solve this if anything like this happens again.

There is a corrupt string in the consent code - and here is the problem. It should be fixed. I approach each publisher individually. There is no one-size-fits-all method of repair. Therefore, access to AdSense is required. Different repair methods should be used for each publisher.
The work is divided into two stages.

repair (ads will be displayed and immediately start earning).
final - after about 24 hours the ads will work without repair codes.

